# Simple matplotlib Annotating example not working in Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

Code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

t = np.arange(0.0, 5.0, 0.01)
s = np.cos(2*np.pi*t)
line, = ax.plot(t, s, lw=2)

ax.annotate('local max', xy=(2, 1), xytext=(3, 1.5),
            arrowprops=dict(facecolor='black', shrink=0.05),
            )

ax.set_ylim(-2,2)
plt.show()
```

from http://matplotlib.org/1.2.0/users/annotations_intro.html
return

`TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable`

I manged to fixed it with

```
xxx={'facecolor':'black', 'shrink':0.05}
ax.annotate('local max', xy=(2, 1), xytext=(3, 1.5),
            arrowprops=xxx,
            )
```

Is this the best way ?
Also what caused this problem ? ( I know that this started with Python 2.7)

So if somebody know more, please share.

Comment: The code you posted works ok for me (using ipython with python v2.7.3). Perhaps you have a variable named "dict", which prevents the built-in behaviour of `dict`?

Comment: You are correct. I am testing some examples with ipython notebook, so dict was used previously. I had to do `del dict`, to make it work. You can write this as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the code looks fine and runs ok on my machine, it seems that you may have a variable named "dict" (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14979488/why-python-allows-to-overwrite-builtin-constants) for reference).  A couple of ideas on how to check:

- use [Pylint](http://www.pylint.org/).
- if you suspect one specific builtin, try checking it's type (`type(dict)`), or look at the properties/functions it has (`dir(dict)`).
- open a fresh notebook and try again, if you only observe the problem in interactive session.
- try alternate syntax to initialise the dictionary

  ```
  ax.annotate('local max', xy=(2, 1), xytext=(3, 1.5),
      arrowprops={'facecolor':'black', 'shrink':0.05})
  ```
- try explicitly instancing a variable of this type, using the alternate syntax (as you did already).